# How does ifconfig find a machine's external IP address?

Tags: ip, internet

Normally when I want to check the external IP address of a given machine, I simply `curl` some external website that sends me a response telling me what my IP address appears to it. However, I've noticed that `ifconfig` has my external IP address listed as well.

Does `ifconfig` have some sort of "canonical" source on the web that it sends requests to determine a machine's IP address or does it have some other method of finding out a machine's IP address?

Comment: `ifconfig` doesn't do that. I feel like you confuse something in the output. Care to provide some example output?

Comment: Ah is the `inet addr` parameter the IP address on the local network (for reference I'm using the sample output at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig)?

Comment: Eh, well at any rate the `inet addr` I'm seeing matches my actual external IP address.

Comment: Is your machine, perchance, connected directly to a modem or uplink, that is without a router in between the machine and the internet. Thus NAT would not be needed and the machine would know its 'external' IP.

Comment: Probably not; I'm on a computer in my school's computer lab and I suspect there are far too many computers for that. Then again I have no idea what the network topology here is (in general I know very little about networking) and maybe we're just really spoiled.

Comment: @Adaephon: Even if I were hidden behind NAT, how would `ifconfig` (and by extension my machine) know that?

Comment: `ifconfig` wouldn't know. Your machine has no way to know it's behind a NAT unless it contacts some host outside the NAT which tells it what IP address it's seeing your machine as.

Comment: Many universities got onto the Internet early on when there were plenty of IP addresses available, so they don't need to use NAT.

Comment: @badcook: If you were hidden behind NAT, `ifconfig` would indeed have no idea about it and would/should not know the eternal IP (that is your network address on the other side of the NAT). But your `ifconfig` seems to know the 'external' IP, which indicates that there may be no NAT in place. -- An easy (although maybe not fool-proof) test would be: Does `ifconfig` also show an IP starting with '10.', '172.16.' or '192.168.'? This would imply a private network. Almost any other IP would be public. (I'm not asking for your IP address in case you don't want your location/school to be known.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configuring the external address is the job of `ifconfig`.  It just reads the kernel data structures that it wrote the address into.  It works even if your computer is disconnected from the network.  `ifconfig` can fully configure the network while the computer is isolated from the network, and if the configuration was done correctly, the network will being funtioning as soon as the network cable is connected.

The loopback address [127.0.0.1] is configured on a software device which exists even if no network cards are installed in the computer.  This allows local connections using protocols such as TCP and UDP.  This simplifies software development as it is not necessary to provide special services for local connections.

EDIT: `ifconfig` normally won't know if you have configured an IP address which is already in use.  If the network interface is connected to the internet, it is possible to `ARP` the network to see if the address is in use.  This is not a required feature of `ifconfig` and multiple computers with the same IP address is not an unusual occurrence.  If `ifconfig` or other software determines the configured address is incorrect, the usual response is to issue a warning message.

It is also possible for `ifconfig` to configure the device for the wrong network.  It is the responsibility of the user to ensure the configuration provided to `ifconfig` is correct.  There are other tools which perform the same functions as `ifconfig` and the same restrictions apply.

There are three ranges of IP addresses defined for private networks.  Thee are 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, and 192.168.0.0/16.  It is common to configure computers on these address ranges.  In such cases, their IP address will be different from their "Public" IP address on the Internet.  The "Public" IP address will belong to a device connected to the Internet which performs Network Address Translation (NAT) to allow computers on the private network to communicate with the Internet.  Computers on a home network almost always have a private network address.  Most home routers will perform NAT for computers on the local (private) network.

Comment: How does `ifconfig` write addresses into kernel data structures? For example, (and forgive me if this is a very stupid question), how would `ifconfig` know whether my public IP address is already "taken"?

Comment: @badcook `ifconfig` normally won't know if your public IP address is already taken.  See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

`ifconfig` is simply a tool for setting/getting the current make up of your network interfaces. When you run it, it simply returns this information back to you. You can use it to query all the devices or an individual interface.

#### Examples

Individual device.

```
$ ifconfig lo
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6119 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8725156 (8.3 MiB)  TX bytes:8725156 (8.3 MiB)
```

All devices.

```
$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f2600000-f2620000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:45792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:45792 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7548353 (7.1 MiB)  TX bytes:7548353 (7.1 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
          inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1254848 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1408361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:699671476 (667.2 MiB)  TX bytes:347243164 (331.1 MiB)
```

#### /proc/net

The information that you can manipulate with `ifconfig` about each network interface is exposed within the Linux kernel under the `/proc/net` file system. If you consult the man page for `ifconfig` you'll notice this section:

```
FILES
       /proc/net/socket
       /proc/net/dev
       /proc/net/if_inet6
```

These are the files that contain some of the networking information. There are other files under `/proc/net` as well.

#### Alternatives to ifconfig, ip

There is an alternative tool called `ip` that you can use to manipulate the networking information as well.

```
$ ip addr show lo
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

#### Networking information

The information such as the IP address is either statically set or dynamically set. When statically set, you typically can use the tool `ifconfig` to set the IP address for a specific network device, such as `eth0`, or `wlan0`.

The alternative, where the IP information is dynamically set, uses a service called DHCP which is a server on the network that computers can connect to, asking the DHCP server to assign it an IP address.

In either case the networking information when determined, is accessible under `/proc/net/*`.

Comment: Hi @slm, is there a device/interface that will show the external ip, and another one that will show the internal ip?

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig cannot show your "external" IP address if you are behind a NAT.  It only configures the address that is provided by the DHCP server to your network interfaces.  If you have e to know your external IP address you should hit a service such as https://ipof.in/txt.

Comment: Or, shameless plug, https://api.ident.me for IPv4, IPv6, or both.